# creating a custom shop page display on archive woocommerce

Tags: plugins, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

Hello guys how are you? i am not that good at developing websites and i need to have more experience. can you guys help me? i had an idea on the screenshot i have on the link below. as you can see i want the circled one to be a category and the other non circled are all the products you have. i tried everything from plugins to editing a custom product archive but it really wont budge. i just want to know if my idea is applicable, doable or not.

Thank you guys always for helping people on codes.
You guys are the best.

Thank you in advance. :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1L6E.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, yes, and there are many ways to achieve this.  The first thing you will want to do is create a child theme or plugin.  One of those two is where you will be adding your code...

This can be done by using wp action *[pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)* there is a great post that Remi Corson has [here](http://www.remicorson.com/modifying-the-current-query-with-pre_get_posts/) to explain more about modifying if only on the archive page:

from on of his examples (with a little mod):

```
// Load our function when hook is set
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_get_design_projects' );
function rc_modify_query_get_design_projects( $query ) {

    // Check if on frontend and main query is modified
    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {

        $query->set( 'cat', '20' ); // whatever your category id is here

    }

}
```

something like the above (very much untested in your environment), but I think you can get the idea here...